# How to modify function epilog and prelog in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I want to change the epilog and prelog of a function as put by gcc compiler. As i am completely new to the gcc can any one please guide me what are the step to be followed.
I want to made some modifications to epilog and prelog to encrypt the return address.
Any help will be most appreciated and welcomed.

Comment: **How many *years* of effort can you afford?** You don't only need to modify the epilog and prolog, you also need to modify the calling conventions and protocols and recompile every piece of software used by your program (including at least the C standard library, whose lowest layers you'll also need to patch)

Comment: So, go see your manager, ask him enough budget for a team of several very qualified compiler engineers working for several years, and come back again. BTW, `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` is a better place to ask, but you should spend a few weeks learning about GCC internals before even starting thinking about it. I've wrote some slides and gave some references on http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html related to that